# interesting bus line probability question

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

there is a guy who gets on the bus at bus stop A and gets off at bus stop B where his work place is located.

There are 4 bus lines which passes through stop A and stop B. Since these buses are old, each bus has a consecutive down time varying between 1-10 days(both included) in a month (30 days).

What is the probability of this man not being able to go to work on random day of the month?

You can think of month as circular 30 days, if a bus brakes down let's say 25th day of the month for 7 days. what it spans is 25-26-27-28-29-30-1-2 days of the month.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it doesnt matter on which day the man is going to work, I just look at the 15th of the month to get out of this circularity thinking.

Then, the probability of him not being able to go to work is when every single bus is out of order at the same time.

To compute the probability of a single bus being out of order, we have to look at the distribution of its down time. The consecutiveness of the downtime does not play any role here as we just dont care about any specific day.

You didnt make it clear how the down times are distributed, so I will just assume all of them have the same probability.
If that is the case, statistically speaking we can replace the bus with another one that has the downtime of $5.5$ days each month (the mean value of $1$ to $10$).

Thus, the probability of him being down is $p=5.5/30=11/60$

The probability of all busses being down is the same time is just 
$$p^4 = \left(\frac{11}{60}\right)^4\approx0.001$$

That means, the man cant get to work in $0.1\%$ of the days.